# Global aggregation is not taking into account all documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Global aggregation is not taking into account all the documents in my elasticsearch.

I have tried to do as the documentation says by placing the global aggregation in the top level.

> Global aggregation defines a single bucket of all the documents within the search execution context. This context is defined by the indices and the document types you’re searching on.
>
> Global aggregators can only be placed as top level aggregators.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs":{
      "all_documents":{
         "global":{},
         "aggs":{
            "all_totals":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"dateReleve"
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "total_clients_cut":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"nbClientCoupe"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the value of `sum_other_doc_count` is expected to be zero, but i'm getting 299932

```
{
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 302644,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "all_documents": {
            "doc_count": 302644,
            "all_totals": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 608,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 299932,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": 1554144600000,
                        "key_as_string": "2019-04-01T18:50:00.000Z",
                        "doc_count": 374,
                        "total_clients_cut": {
                            "value": 178673
                        }
                    },
                    ...
```

But when I increase the size of the terms bucket by doing:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs":{
      "all_documents":{
         "global":{},
         "aggs":{
            "all_totals":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"dateReleve",
                  "size": 10000        <----------------------
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "total_clients_cut":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"nbClientCoupe"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get the expected result which is `sum_other_doc_count` = 0.
Increasing the size of the bucket is not a good practice i think, because we cannot assume how much documents we already have.
So my question is how to get the expected result with the global aggregation.

Comment: What do u want to archive ? When using terme u will have to provide a size.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question about archiving.
Following the documentation the size haven't been mentionned for the avg aggregation so it's not obligatory.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Using the `size` parameter is not necessarily a bad practice, but understanding what's actually happening and the alternatives may be helpful in deciding what is best for your use-case.

As indicated in the documentation:

> The size parameter can be set to define how many term buckets should
>   be returned out of the overall terms list. By default, the node
>   coordinating the search process will request each shard to provide its
>   own top size term buckets and once all shards respond, it will reduce
>   the results to the final list that will then be returned to the
>   client. This means that if the number of unique terms is greater than
>   size, the returned list is slightly off and not accurate (it could be
>   that the term counts are slightly off and it could even be that a term
>   that should have been in the top size buckets was not returned).

Your result set must have a high cardinality for the `dateReleve` field; when the search executes, you're receiving only the **top** number of buckets as decided by the shard queried, which is then returned to the coordinating node which compiles the final list.  You can confirm this by noting you received `"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 608`

As indicated in the documentation, you might want to look at using the Composite aggregation instead:

> Note
>
> If you want to retrieve all terms or all combinations of terms in a
>   nested terms aggregation you should use the Composite aggregation
>   which allows to paginate over all possible terms rather than setting a
>   size greater than the cardinality of the field in the terms
>   aggregation. **The terms aggregation is meant to return the top terms
>   and does not allow pagination.**

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html